# How to create array object and push the same object value in to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have this array named *categories* and i made a loop of it as buttons. I've tried a couple hours to find a way to handle JSON like this:

```
    categories: [
        {
            name: 'Plan',
            values: ['Idea Generation','Naming','Revenue Models','Mockups & Wireframing','Presentation','Team Building']
        },
        {
            name: 'Design',
            values: ['Outsourcing','Logo','Graphics','Templates','UI/UX']
        },
        {
            name: 'Develop', 
            values: ['Hosting','Domain Names','Development','MVP','Payments','Product Demo','Templates']
        },
        {
            name: 'Market', 
            values: ['SNS','Press','Blog','Market Research','Forms & Survey','Analytics','A/B Testing','Advertising']
        },
        {
            name: 'Manage', 
            values: ['Hiring','Project Management','Funding','Legal','Finance','Feedback','Collaboration & Communication','Customer Support','Productivity','Investor Relations']
        },
        {
            name: 'ETC',
            values: ['Articles','Blogs','Learning']
        }
    ]
```

**Check this image:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHx8s.jpg

What i want to achieve is just the same on the json data ABOVE.
For example: When i click on `Idea Generation` button under **Plan** it will create an array like this:

```
    selected_category: [
        {
            name: "Plan",
            value: ["Idea Generation"]
        }
    ]
```

So, if i click another button under the same category "**Plan**" like `Mockups & Wireframing`, it will add on the same `name` on the object:

```
    selected_category: [
        {
            name: "Plan",
            value: ["Idea Generation", "Mockups & Wireframing"]
        }
    ]
```

But if when i click again but on different category **Design** for example it will be like this:

```
    selected_category: [
        {
            name: "Plan",
            value: ["Idea Generation", "Mockups & Wireframing"]
        },
        {
            name: "Design",
            value: ["Outsourcing"]
        }
    ]
```

I'm not familiar to constructing array object data, so i need help here.

Comment: Welcome to SO! These data structures are a far cry away from the finished result in the image. Have you made an attempt at solving this problem, and if so, can you share a [mcve]? If not, this is a bit too broad. See [ask].

Comment: @ggorlen Yes, i have tried several times but im really having a hard time making this one

Comment: Can you post your code? We'll be happy to help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is use vue's v-on attribute (@click) to call a method that has your logic which will add it to the array it would look something like this

```
<button @click(addToSelectedItems(data.name, data.value)>Click me </button>

addToSelectedItems(name, value){
    var index = selected_category.findIndex(c => c.name == name);
    if (index === -1) {
        selected_category.push({
            name: name,
            value: value,
        });
    }
    selected_category[index].value.push(value);

}
```

Syntax might not but right but this is the rough idea

Comment: Thanks @ThatPurpleGuy. Your code works. I just made the value as an array